# ClassNotFoundException inside CRF

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf

I have downloaded CRF package from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/crf/. Unfortunately when I run it I am facing this error. I have tried to change the classpath but it is still not working.

The error:

```
  C:\NER\CRF-1.3\CRF\src\iitb\Segment>java iitb.Segment.Segment all -f samples/us50.conf
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: iitb/Segment/S
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iitb.Segment.Segment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
  Could not find the main class: iitb.Segment.Segment.  Program will exit.
```